# AWS S3 transfer cost between AWS services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my understanding, data transfer between EC2 ans S3 is free.
But other AWS services, such as CodeBuild and Lambda, are the same as EC2?

Comment: Here https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/ under Data Transfer. It is only free for Transfer In, and Out for EC2 (if same region), and CloudFront. `Transfers between S3 buckets or from Amazon S3 to any service(s) within the same AWS Region are free` You have to pay for the rest.

Comment: Lambda upto some number of request is free per month. after that they charges hardly get $40-$50 for big application.

Comment: @Nikhil Thanks.  Where can I find this part 'Transfers between S3 buckets or from Amazon S3 to any service(s) within the same AWS Region are free' ?

Comment: @TakayukiSato It is under the "Data Transfer" tab.